# Method not found in `mongodb::results::UpdateResult`

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to make a CLI app to update a MongoDB document using Rust. This is my code.

```rust
use mongodb::{Client, options::{ClientOptions, ResolverConfig}};
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use bson::doc;
use tokio;
    
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client_uri = 
    dotenv::var("MONGODB_URI").expect("You must set the MONGODB_URI environment var!");
    let db_name = dotenv::var("MONGODB_NAME").expect("You must set the MONGODB_NAME environment var!");

    println!("Enter an email: ");
    let mut email = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut email).expect("failed to readline");

    let options =
        ClientOptions::parse_with_resolver_config(&client_uri, ResolverConfig::cloudflare())
            .await?;
    let client = Client::with_options(options)?;

    let filter: mongodb::bson::Document = doc! { "email" : &email.trim_end() };
    let update: mongodb::bson::Document = doc! { "$set" : {"temp" : "5" }};

    let user: mongodb::bson::Document = client
        .database(&db_name)
        .collection("users")
        .update_one(filter, update, None)
        .await?
        .unwrap();

        
    let base_user = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&user).unwrap();

    println!("{}", base_user);

    Ok(())
}
```

I have almost done it, but my VS Code terminal always give me this error:

```
no method named `unwrap` found for struct `mongodb::results::UpdateResult` in the current scope 
method not found in `mongodb::results::UpdateResult
```

Comment: You call `?` on the result from `await` which already unwraps the `Result` and yields the contained `UpdateResult`, which in turn does not have to be unwrapped

Comment: When I remove `unwrap()`
I get another Error:
`?` operator has incompatible types

expected struct `bson::Document`, found struct `mongodb::results::UpdateResult`

note: `?` operator cannot convert from `mongodb::results::UpdateResult` to `bson::Document`

Comment: Then just call unwrap whithout the `?` operator before it ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit If I just use `.await.unwrap();` I get complain mismatched types: expected struct `bson::Document`, found struct `mongodb::results::UpdateResult`

Comment: Yes an `UpdateResult` type wont give you a Document. You can retrive the document by using the `upserted_id` field of the `UpdateResult` and doing a 2nd query after the update has been resoved...

Comment: Thank you guys! Now my issues are solved